# Retrieve and Show Node in Listview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there anyone here could help on how to retrieve those class section inside the black box and show it in listview and if i add more class section it will add automatically in my listview. Thanks

[image: Click this to see image]

Comment: is it a json string?

Comment: Please add your code in which you try to retrive those classes.

Answer (score 0):

So, if your database structure is like this..

```
teacher{
        VRdn7....f1{
                    name:"name"
                    .....
                    class{
                          key1{
               -->             className:"c1"  }
                          key2{
               -->             className:"c2"  }
                          key3{
               -->             className:"c3"  }
                         }
                   }
       }
```

And if you want values of className then,

```
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("teacher").child("VRdn7......f1");

    db.child("class").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


            String className = dataSnapshot.child("className").getValue().toString();
            //This will get all values of className inside "teacher\VRdn7....f1\class\***\"
            // Now create adapter for listview, and then add values in a list....
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
```